# Sign a function call using private key solana/web3

Tags: anchor, web3.js

I am trying to call a certain function of my custom smart contract on the solana blockchain using solana web3. I am trying to sign the function call using my private key instead of signing it through the phantom wallet. Is there any possible way to do that?
the code which I am using:

```
adminKeypair=bs58.decode(privateKey) //private key is a string
let adminSigner = Keypair.fromSecretKey(adminKeypair);

await program.rpc.enterUserInfo({
 accounts: {
        signer: adminSigner.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      },
})
```

The error which I am getting is that:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Signature verification failed
    at Transaction.serialize (transaction.ts:736:1)
    at w.send (provider.ts:116:1)
    at async Object.enterUserInfo (rpc.ts:26:1)
    at async enterUserInfo (utils.js:190:1)
    at async _enterUserInfo (App.js:135:1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `signers` property with the keypair inside:

```
await program.rpc.enterUserInfo({
  accounts: {
    signer: adminSigner.publicKey,
    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
  },
  signers: [adminSigner],
})
```

Comment: Im doing this in react. Even if I dont use the phantom wallet connected to the app explicitly, the transaction has two signers: adminSigner and wallet.

Is there anyway to stop the wallet id from signing